# Changing JOptionPane background color based on If statement

Tags: java, swing, background, joptionpane

I would like to change the background color of a JOptionPane message based on an If statement.  If a user hits one button, a green message background would come up otherwise a red one will.  With the following code, both messages come up one after the other. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
if (e.getSource() == cmdYes)
                 new UIManager();
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",new   ColorUIResource(0,255,0));
             UIManager.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(0,255,0));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Green Message", 
                        "Green", 
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            if (e.getSource() == cmdNo)
                 new UIManager();
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));
             UIManager.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red Message", 
                        "Red", 
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: how do you initiate cmdYes and cmdNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change like this. you miss this `{}` brackets..

```
if (e.getSource() == cmdYes) {
            new UIManager();
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", new ColorUIResource(0, 255, 0));
            UIManager.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(0, 255, 0));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Green Message", "Green", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
if (e.getSource() == cmdNo) {
            new UIManager();
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 0));
            UIManager.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 0));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red Message", "Red", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Arr!! I knew it was something as simple as that... Thank you!